# Mark PDF as Adobe PDF

Tags: software-recommendation, printing, pdf, adobe

There are several journal websites (typically Taylor and Francis) that require that all PDF files submitted to it for reviewing should be Adobe PDFs. The submission engine will not accept a PDF generated by LaTeX or OpenOffice.

To do this conversion, one has to actually boot into Windows, open the PDF file with Adobe Acrobat Reader, save as a new file and then upload the paper to the journal website. This is is kind of a funny procedure and hampers the freedom.

What software can I install, so that I can denote the PDF as an Adobe PDF, so that I can easily submit the paper to the journal website.

Comment: Why do they only accept Adobe PDFs? Do they have problems with other files and if yes: why should you mark them as Adobe PDF instead of asking "Why don't you accept other PDF creators?"

Comment: You should simply boycott a Journal that imposes such requirements. Open Science can only impose itself if researchers stop complying with this sort of nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably also dependent on the PDF version:

- In my document headers created with LibreOffice, the version 1.4 is having fewer header information.
- Using the print function (f.e. firefox) uses 1.5, which is the same like a PDF I created with the newest M$ Word (2010).

Could you try out PDFsam (pdf split and merge) ? It has the option to choose the pdf version naming also the related Acrobat version.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install Adobe Acrobat Reader in Ubuntu and thus you have no need to open Windows anymore.

**For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

1. Add repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
   ```
2. Update your system

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Adobe Reader, and font extensions

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y install acroread acroread-fonts
   ```

**For Ubuntu 13.10**

1. Download latest Adobe Reader version, from [here](http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb). It's only 32 bit.
2. Install package, forcing to accept 32-bit version and any errors:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture ~/Downloads/AdbeRdr*.deb
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
3. Add the missing libraries: (skip this if your OS is 32 bit already)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386 lib32stdc++6
   ```
4. Run for first time, to get icon in Unity menu bar.

   ```
   acroread ~/test.pdf
   ```